# Trying to get a access token for Onenote in Python 3.7

Tags: python, access-token, onenote, onenote-api

Hello I'm tying to get a access token from code-flow as described here:

[OneNote authentication and permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/how-to/onenote-auth)

I already received the code from the first step

```
https://your-redirect-uri?code=M57010781-9e8c-e31e-ca0d-46bc104236c4
```

Then I tried to get a access token with that code:

```
payload2 = {'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
               'client_id': 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx',
                'client_secret' : 'secret',
                'code' : 'M57010781-9e8c-e31e-ca0d-46bc104236c4',
               'redirect_uri' : 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf',}

        b_url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?'
    new_tok_req = urlencode(payload2)
    new_url = b_url+new_tok_req
```

The value in "new_url" is now

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=secret&code=M57010781-9e8c-e31e-ca0d-46bc104236c4&redirect_uri=https%253A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf
```

Then I sent the post with the following method:

```
 r2 = requests.post(new_url)
```

This triggers the following error from the server:

> b'{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The provided request must have content-type \'application/x-www-form-urlencoded\'."}'

I cannot find the problem. 
For me the URL in `new_url`  looks well formatted.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can maybe someone tell me, if the url is well formatted?

Comment: Should I provide additional information to clarify the problem and if yes, which information?